# Repeating multidimensional array object in angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[Object{ 82893u82378237832={ id=8, no=1, type="event", name="Sample1"}}, Object{ 128129wq378237832={ id=9, no=1, type="event", name="Sample2"}} ]
```

Now ignoring the first part which is just a random token i want to get the array inside that. i.e. **id**,**no**,**type**,**name** and display them in an ng-repeat, how can i achieve this?

This is how i create the above array:

```
var obj = {};
obj[data.responseData] = {
    id: 8,
    no: 1,
    type: 'event',
    name: ''
}

$scope.items.push(obj);
```

Comment: your format is invalid...

Comment: Sorry if it is i didn't know how to copy the full array from my console so i just typed it.

Comment: That is not an array, but an object.

Comment: Oh yes, potato potato :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't include an array.

Anyway here's a good example.

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform an array to another array and use ng-repeat in a similar way that I've done.

Html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl"> 
        <div ng-repeat="item in myArr">
            {{item}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    var arr = [{
        myId: '82893u82378237832',
        id: 8,
        no: 1,
        type: "event",
        name: "Sample1"
    }, {
        myId: '128129wq378237832',
        id: 9,
        no: 1,
        type: "event",
        name: "Sample2"
    }];

    // mapped the new object without myId
    $scope.myArr = arr.map(function (item) {
        return {
            id: item.id,
            no: item.no,
            type: item.type,
            name: item.name
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k287asto/).

Comment: Okay the thing is i want to be able to remove each object form the array at a click of a button that is why i added the key, how would i achieve that with your way? :)

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example?

Comment: I mean i want to remove/delete a specific object in that array in an ng-repeat

Comment: If you want to delete it then you can use the delete keyword as in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/4cwep2h0/ . If you want to hide it from display you should use the ng-if or ng-hide directive on the specific element. In the first example I just added a json display, but you can do it the way you want to.